# Play Store Publishing

Tags: android, google-play

Is it necessary to have a website to publish to the Google Play Store?

If so, is there a way around this without paying and setting up your own website?

Comment: What makes you think you need a website to publish to the Google Play store? Have you tried? This is really a question for Google Play support; it's quite a long way away from programming, per se.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Play policies

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not necessary to have a web site in order to publish to the Google Play Store.

Comment: Good answer, short and clear!